Why is \cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_put_right:Nn { Nc } deprecated when the recommended \clist_put_right:Nv doesn't give the expected result?
Context
(I'm trying to get around the problem of storing a pointer to the current value of a comma list instead of its value in the case of nested [comma lists] (see Custom command with nested sequences and argument with macro).)
In the following MCE, I'm displaying biographies sorted alphabetically by people's surnames. To do this:

For each person, I create an individual comma list containing the surname, first name and a short biography,
I combine these comma lists into an external comma list,
I sort this outer comma list, which turns out to be sorted on the first elements of the inner comma lists.

The working but impractical case
This works well if the inner comma lists have different names, in this case l_biography_one_clist and l_biography_two_clist:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_biographies_clist

\clist_set:Nn \l_biography_one_clist { Smith, John,  {Short~ biography~ of~  John} }
\clist_gput_right:Nn \g_biographies_clist \l_biography_one_clist

\clist_set:Nn \l_biography_two_clist { Jones, Alice, {Short~ biography~ of~ Alice} }
\clist_gput_right:Nn \g_biographies_clist \l_biography_two_clist

\clist_sort:Nn \g_biographies_clist
{
  \str_compare:eNeTF { #1 } > { #2 }
  { \sort_return_swapped: }
  { \sort_return_same: }
}

\clist_show:N \g_biographies_clist

\begin{description}
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \g_biographies_clist {
  \clist_gset:Ne \g_tmpa_clist {#1}
  \item[
      \text_titlecase_first:n{\clist_item:en \g_tmpa_clist {2}}
      \c_space_tl
      \text_titlecase_first:n{\clist_item:en \g_tmpa_clist {1}}
      :
    ]
    \clist_item:en \g_tmpa_clist {3}
  }
\end{description}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}

Note that \clist_show:N \g_biographies_clist returns:
The comma-delimited list \g_biographies_clist contains the elements (without outer braces):
> {\l_biography_two_clist }
> {\l_biography_one_clist }.

and the result is as expected (Alice Jones before John Smith):

The not working but practical case
But this would be tedious and not automatic in the case of numerous biographies. So I'd like the (different) names of the internal comma lists to be programmatically obtained, using something like {l_biography_ \int_use:N \g_biography_int _clist} for an integer \g_biography_int which would be incremented.
Before this step, I want to adapt the previous MCE to manually number the names of the inner comma lists. This requires, for example
\clist_set:Nn \l_biography_one_clist {...}
to be replaced by:
\clist_set:cn {l_biography_1_clist} {...}
which is correct, but:
\clist_gput_right:Nn \g_biographies_clist \l_biography_one_clist
should be replaced by:
\clist_gput_right:Nc \g_biographies_clist {l_biography_2_clist}.
The problem is that \clist_gput_right:Nc doesn't exist and, if such a variant is created:
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_gput_right:Nn { Nc }
the compilation fails with the following error:

! LaTeX error: Variant form ‘Nc’ deprecated for base form
(LaTeX) ‘\clist_gput_right:Nn’. Do not change an argument
(LaTeX) from type ‘n’ to type ‘c’: use a variant ‘v’?

OK, let's try it with v:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_biographies_clist

\clist_set:cn {l_biography_1_clist} { Smith, John,  {Short~ biography~ of~  John} }
\clist_gput_right:Nv \g_biographies_clist {l_biography_1_clist}

\clist_set:cn {l_biography_2_clist} { Jones, Alice, {Short~ biography~ of~ Alice} }
\clist_gput_right:Nv \g_biographies_clist {l_biography_2_clist}

\clist_sort:Nn \g_biographies_clist
{
  \str_compare:eNeTF { #1 } > { #2 }
  { \sort_return_swapped: }
  { \sort_return_same: }
}

\clist_show:N \g_biographies_clist

\begin{description}
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \g_biographies_clist {
    \clist_gset:Ne \g_tmpa_clist {#1}
  \item[
      \text_titlecase_first:n{\clist_item:en \g_tmpa_clist {2}}
      \c_space_tl
      \text_titlecase_first:n{\clist_item:en \g_tmpa_clist {1}}
      :
    ]
    \clist_item:en \g_tmpa_clist {3}
  }
\end{description}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}

Note that \clist_show:N \g_biographies_clist returns:
The comma list \g_biographies_clist contains the items (without outer braces):
> {Alice}
> {John}
> {Jones}
> {Brief biography of Alice}
> {Brief biography of John}
> {Smith}.

which shows that the nested comma list structure has been lost, and the result is not as expected:

The rebellion affair
OK, let's be rebellious and use \cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_gput_right:Nn { Nc } anyway:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_gput_right:Nn { Nc }

\clist_new:N \g_biographies_clist

\clist_set:cn {l_biography_1_clist} { Smith, John,  {Short~ biography~ of~  John} }
\clist_gput_right:Nc \g_biographies_clist {l_biography_1_clist}

\clist_set:cn {l_biography_2_clist} { Jones, Alice, {Short~ biography~ of~ Alice} }
\clist_gput_right:Nc \g_biographies_clist {l_biography_2_clist}

\clist_sort:Nn \g_biographies_clist
{
  \str_compare:eNeTF { #1 } > { #2 }
  { \sort_return_swapped: }
  { \sort_return_same: }
}

\clist_show:N \g_biographies_clist

\begin{description}
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \g_biographies_clist {
    \clist_gset:Ne \g_tmpa_clist {#1}
  \item[
      \text_titlecase_first:n{\clist_item:en \g_tmpa_clist {2}}
      \c_space_tl
      \text_titlecase_first:n{\clist_item:en \g_tmpa_clist {1}}
      :
    ]
    \clist_item:en \g_tmpa_clist {3}
  }
\end{description}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}

Ok, we have this error:

! LaTeX error: The variant form ‘Nc’ is deprecated for the basic form
(LaTeX) ‘\clist_gput_right:Nn’. Do not change a
(LaTeX) from type ‘n’ to type ‘c’: use a ‘v’ variant ?

but \clist_show:N \g_biographies_clist returns the expected:
The comma list \g_biographies_clist contains the items (without outer braces):
> {\l_biography_two_clist }
> {\l_biography_one_clist }.

and the result is as expected:

Question
Why is \cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_gput_right:Nn { Nc } deprecated when it is the only one to give the expected result?

I think \clist_item:fr is a typo in your examples

Also \c_titlecase_first:n and \c_item:en

Short answer: it does not give the expected result…

@mbert Sorry for the typos! They are fixed now.

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_gput_right:Nn { Nc } is deprecated because n and c are not the same argument types. n is a braced token list, while c is a single token. Yes you can use/abuse the fact that tex allows a single token in place of a token list but this is bad practice and against the spirit of expl3.
For your use case, you can just use a global sequence instead of a clist so the final result isn't flattened.
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_biographies_seq

\clist_set:cn {l_biography_1_clist} { Smith, John, {Brief~ biography~ of~ John} }
\seq_gput_right:Nv \g_biographies_seq {l_biography_1_clist}

\clist_set:cn {l_biography_2_clist} { Jones, Alice, {Brief~ biography~ of~ Alice} }
\seq_gput_right:Nv \g_biographies_seq {l_biography_2_clist}

\seq_sort:Nn \g_biographies_seq
{
  \str_compare:eNeTF { #1 } > { #2 }
  { \sort_return_swapped: }
  { \sort_return_same: }
}

\seq_show:N \g_biographies_seq

\begin{description}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_biographies_seq {
    \clist_gset:Nn \g_tmpa_clist {#1}
  \item[
      \text_titlecase_first:n{\clist_item:Nn \g_tmpa_clist {2}}
      \c_space_tl
      \text_titlecase_first:n{\clist_item:Nn \g_tmpa_clist {1}}
      :
    ]
    \clist_item:Nn \g_tmpa_clist {3}
  }
\end{description}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}

The log shows
The sequence \g_biographies_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {Jones,Alice,Brief biography of Alice}
>  {Smith,John,Brief biography of John}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.19 \seq_show:N \g_biographies_seq

and the output is

Note those \clist_item:en should be \clist_item:Nn.

It does the trick, thanks! But why using a global sequence instead of a clist makes the final result not flattened?

@DenisBitouzé The idea of \clist_put_right is to append items to the big clist. If you want a clists of clists, you'll need an extra pair of braces somewhere. \seq_put_right is just adding a single new item, you can't add multiple items at once
